# Nagios XI: Provide Multiple Arguments to a Command

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I have created a custom plugin in order to monitor a parameter using Nagios XI. To execute that plugin remotely I must use:

`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H [IP_ADDR] -c [PLUGIN_NAME] -a [ARGUMENT]`

Having made appropriate changes in `nrpe.cfg` and `/etc/sudoers`, I could get correct results.

But, I need to provide multiple arguments to the command. What should be the syntax I must use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it a comment if i though anyone could read it. In my command.cfg I had made this

```
# 'clear_printqueue' event handler command definition
define command{
        command_name    clear_printqueue
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5666 -c clear_printqueue -a  "/PrinterName:$ARG1$" "/ServiceState:$SERVICESTATE$" "/StateType:$SERVICESTATETYPE$" "/ServiceAttempt:$SERVICEATTEMPT$" "/MaxServiceAttempts:$MAXSERVICEATTEMPTS$"
        }
```

I only have Nagios Core 3.4.4 but I hope this might help. My ini file on the client contained this

```
clear_printqueue = cscript.exe //T:30 //NoLogo scripts\\lib\\wrapper.vbs scripts\\nagiosClear-PrintQueue.vbs "$ARG1$" "$ARG2$" "$ARG3$" "$ARG4$" "$ARG5$"
```

`$ARG#$` gets passed to the script where it runs. In short I just passed the quoted arguments with spaces in between.